# Why does VS2010 allow for the concept of "include in project"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm still learning the basics of how VS2010 sees the world. Apparently, you can optionally "include" a file in a project. I'm a bit confused by this: If a file is version-controlled, AND the file is within the project directory, shouldn't it implicitly be "included" in the project? If not, what's the use case where a version-controlled file in the project directory should NOT be included in the project?

=== Addition ===

Based on the answers I've gotten so far, maybe I should rephrased my question: What does it mean for a file to be "included" in a project?

Comment: Example - files in folder == all clothes you have, project == dress for casual dinner. You not gonna put all t-shirts you happen to have just because you have them, you will only chose things you need OR must wear.

Comment: Right, but I'm looking for someone to explain to me what "include in project" actually means. Why should any version controlled file not be part of the project? What's the downside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A project needs to know about files in order for compilation and distribution to occur.  Just because you have a file that's under source-control, doesn't mean that it will be compiled if the project is unaware of it.

Also, you may want to include files as part of a distribution package. We do this quite often for our web projects that we distribute using [web app gallery](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/).

Conversely, you could have documentation or sql scripts that you version control, but do not want them to be part of the project.

**EDIT:** In answer to your update, what it means for a file to be included in a project is that the file is actually added to the `.csproj` or `.vbproj` file and will be used during compilation and/or distribution. VS does differentiate if the file is `Content` or if it needs to `Compile` it. This can be seen by clicking on the file in Solution Explorer and looking at the `Build Action` property.

Comment: Can you clarify: If you "include" a file in the project, does that imply that the file is part of the build process?

Comment: Not necessarily, lets say that your writing a web app and you need content (images, css, etc). You can create them separately, but you'll need to right-click and include them in the project for distribution. Same could be for a web page that you've created externally.

Comment: I should clarify: in Solution Explorer, you can select "Show All" and then right-click on a file to include it in your project.

Comment: Ok, very interesting. Next question: What happens if a file is "included in project" but NOT present in source control? I'm investigating the contents of a "Service References" directory, and I see a bunch of files listed that do not exist in source control.

Comment: They sound like possible distribution files for the application. You may run into an issue if the solution is ever created from source control. You might want to add those files to source control for that solution.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't want random files that happen to be in the project directory included in source control.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. If a file is intended to be version-controlled, why wouldn't it *also* be included in the project?

Comment: "Because I said so", or for any other reason, like, I'm too lazy to create a folder for stuff that's version controlled but not part of the project. Why make the assumption that everything in the folder is part of the project?

Answer (score 3):

We do sometimes put documentation (pdfs) or drawings/schematics in the project folder and under version control but you don't need them inside the visual studio project (especially when they are not being distributed because they are for internal use only).

Answer (score 1):

Excluding the file from your project can be useful if the file is related to the project but not necessarily needed in the solution.

**Example** 
If I need some test XML for an application that i'm writing; that is designed to normally be pulling this from a WCF service, it can be useful to keep that file in the directory for a development environment where I use IO to get the XML for testing, but I don't necessarily want it in my solution which is source controlled.

Answer (score 1):

When you exclude a file from a project is no longer compiled or embedded, then when you want to include it again you can do so without having lost your settings.

Comment: In this case, the file I'm working with is not a source file. So why would it matter if it is or isn't included in the project?

Comment: Potentially there is no difference, they simply didn't want to implement a separate set of functionality for files that aren't compiled, embedded, copied et al. more than likely if you read up on how projects are compiled there is some difference between how the files are handled that would only affect you if you were writing custom build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you e.g. copy a file (containing a helpful class which want to have in your project) into a folder of your project, then you will see ... nothing. You have to check the option "Show all files" of the solution explorer and the copied file can be seen, but it is still "greyed out". No you can choose the menuitem **Include in project** and that file will be integrated in your project and a pending change (add) for your source control is added too. Visual Studio doesn't include all files it can find in the project folder automatically to the project - and that is a good feature.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues explained to me a scenario in which a version-controlled file should NOT be part of the project. Here's the idea:

- A developer writes some new code.
- The code is experimental, and not intended to be part of the normal build.
- The easiest way to exclude the file from the build is to NOT include it in the project, but still version-control it.
- This way, the file can be shared with other developers, but not break the build.

Comment: This is what branches in version control are for. What happens if your experimental work touches existing files in your project ? In that scenario then you can't commit without messing things up for everyone, so your own changes are not really in version control at all. The concept of having a file in the project which is not actually part of the project to me makes no sense whatsoever.